# Spark structured streaming arbitrary state GroupState.hasTimedOut is never occur with flatMapGroupWithState

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, state, spark-structured-streaming

`hasTimedOut` method is never `true` in my arbitrary state processing function `updateState`

```
def updateWithEvent(tagCount: TagCount, inputsSize: Int): TagCount = {
  TagCount(tagCount.tag, tagCount.count + inputsSize)
}

def updateState(
                 tag: String,
                 inputs: Iterator[ExtendedTweet],
                 oldState: GroupState[TagCount]
               ): Iterator[TagsStatus] = {

  val state = oldState.getOption.getOrElse(TagCount(tag, 0))
  val rows = inputs.toSeq.sortBy(_.createdAt.getTime)
  val newState = updateWithEvent(state, rows.length)

  rows.toIterator.flatMap { input =>
    if (oldState.hasTimedOut) {
      println("hasTimedOut is never true")
      oldState.remove()
      Iterator(TagsStatus(input.createdAt, input.post, input.author, input.tag, 1))
    } else {
      oldState.update(newState)
      oldState.setTimeoutTimestamp(input.createdAt.getTime, "30 seconds")
      Iterator(TagsStatus(input.createdAt, input.post, input.author, newState.tag, newState.count))
    }
  }
}
```

called in

```
val memorySink = tweetsStream
  .withWatermark("createdAt", "30 seconds")
  .groupByKey(_.tag)
  .flatMapGroupsWithState(OutputMode.Update(), GroupStateTimeout.EventTimeTimeout())(updateState)
  .writeStream
  .format("memory")
  .outputMode("update")
  .queryName("tweets_stream")
  .start()
```

With these parameters I got this output:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------+---------+
|          createdAt|                post|             author|    tag|tagsCount|
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------+---------+
|2019-07-10 18:20:22|Lots of great con...|        Seth Martin|bigdata|        1|
|2019-07-10 18:20:29|DF > Machine lear...|  Mr Data Scientist|bigdata|        2|
|2019-07-10 18:20:31|Samsung Galaxy Wa...|              NoSQL|bigdata|        3|
|2019-07-10 18:20:42|Sunday Briefing #...|  Mr Data Scientist|bigdata|        4|
|2019-07-10 18:20:42|CCA131 Demystify ...|              niken|bigdata|        6|
|2019-07-10 18:20:44|Setting alerts in...|              NoSQL|bigdata|        6|
|2019-07-10 18:20:47|CCA131 Demystify ...|   Javascript30 Bot|bigdata|       11|
|2019-07-10 18:20:47|CCA131 Demystify ...|100 Days Of ML Code|bigdata|       11|
|2019-07-10 18:20:47|CCA131 Demystify ...|     BFTawfik Bot 2|bigdata|       11|
|2019-07-10 18:20:47|CCA131 Demystify ...|        CodersNotes|bigdata|       11|
|2019-07-10 18:20:47|CCA131 Demystify ...|           Adrinbot|bigdata|       11|
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------+---------+
```

I expect to remove the old state when window timeout is expired. And count tags from 1 again. Not from number of counts from previous state

Comment: You're setting the event time out for each event in your iterator, you only need to set it once.

Comment: I used the approach when I set the smallest timestamp + additional time to setTimeoutTimestamp, but watermark still doesn't group my data by time and hasTimedOut doesn't work as I expect

Comment: Should I handle that timeout timestamp manually in my `updateState` function?

Comment: I have achieved desired effect by applying 
      .groupBy(
        window($"createdAt", "10 minutes"),
        $"tag")
      .count()
But it is challenging to achieve the same effect with arbitrary state processing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your "if(oldState.hasTimedOut)" statement is included in flatMap. It must be outside of flatMap. Try to change your code like my following example:

```
  def updateState(user :String,
                        inputs :Iterator[InputRecord1],
                         oldState :GroupState[SessionState]): Iterator[OutputRecord1] ={

    var output :Iterator[OutputRecord1] = Iterator()

    if(oldState.hasTimedOut){ 
      val state = oldState.get
      oldState.remove()
      output = Iterator(OutputRecord1(user, state.numSum, state.last_event_time))

    }else{

        for(input <- inputs) {
          if (!oldState.exists) {
            val newState = updateSessionState(SessionState(user, 0, new Timestamp(0L)), input)
            oldState.update(newState)
            oldState.setTimeoutTimestamp(newState.last_event_time.getTime, "5 seconds")

          } else {
            val newState = updateSessionState(oldState.get, input)
            oldState.update(newState)
            oldState.setTimeoutTimestamp(newState.last_event_time.getTime, "5 seconds")

          }
        }

    }


    output
  }
```

I have ever encountered same problem with you, till I change my code like this, the problem solved. I guess when the state time-out, spark will call method "updateState" once with no record pass into it, the inputs Iterator is empty, as iterator is empty, code in flatMap will not be executed. meanwhile "if(oldState.hasTimedOut)" statement is included in flatMap, it never be run.

Comment: This is super helpful. From what I can tell, the flatMapGroupsWithState examples have this wrong in the Spark The Definitive Guide book as well as a bunch of online examples. They have the oldState.hasTimedOut within the loop which never gets called in the case that it would be true. Thanks for providing this, I can't believe this hasn't been said elsewhere.

Comment: I'm glad the answer help you.